# ¿Por qué mi bucle sigue solicitando datos aún cuando a no cumple las condiciones del do-while?

Tags: java

quería hacer un programa que tuviese la función de sumar números. Tiene 15 intentos y al llegar a quince quiero que acabe. Al mismo tiempo, quisiera que el programa finalice en cuanto el usuario introduzca un valor superior a 1000. No sé exactamente que está fallando de momento, pero el bucle sigue solicitando datos aún cuando el valor anterior es mayor a 1000

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int suma =0;
    int i;
    int a;
    int j=15;
    boolean menor;
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);
    do {
        a=teclado.nextInt();
        for (i=0; i<15;i++){
            a=teclado.nextInt();
            menor = (a<1000);
            if (menor = true);
            suma = suma+a;
            if (menor= false);
            break;
        }
    }while (a<1000);
}
```

Comment: Evita borrar publicaciones y volver a ponerlas exactamente igual. Ademas de que perdemos la historia de los comentarios, eso penaliza tu cuenta...

Comment: mas alla de la logica muy confusa, hay un error grave y es dentro de los if.. estas igualando la variable (no comparandola) y no da error, porque es una variable boolenaa.. cambia = por == dentro de los if, y sera mucho mejor...

Comment: el bucle do while ejecuta una sentencia especificada, hasta que la condición de comprobación se evalúa como falsa...por eso si ingresas primero un numero mayor a 1000 este te solicitara otro por que aun no se evalúa la comprobación

Answer (score 0):

A mi parecer la lógica del programa está mal implementada.
Si buscamos hacer un programa que tenga 15 intentos y que en caso de introducir un valor superior a 1000 el programa finalice, creo que este código se ajusta más:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int suma =0;
    int a;
    
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int contador = 0;
    boolean salir = false;      
    do {
        a = teclado.nextInt();
        if(a<1000) {
            suma = suma + a;
        }else {
            salir=true;
        }
        contador++;
    }while(contador <= 15 && salir == false);
    
}
```

Espero te sea de ayuda!
Un saludo.